# Easy way to rotate all vertices along desired shape?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I want to make the "tail" follow the blue line from the picture:
[image] Is there any easy way to do it?

Trying to rotate each point looks messy as I do have to rotate and drag back to position:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Curve modifier? Bend Modifier?

Comment: @vklidu I will go to read about both of them. Thank you! (beginner question, I know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is final purpose of your curved shape, but you can consider to try ... **Curve** object with

- *Shape > Resolution* 8
- *Geometry > Bevel >* **Depth** to something you like
- *Geometry > Bevel >* **Resolution** to zero
  (it brings default round profile shape to square, like your)

[image]

You can easily adjust curvature and if you would need to continue with mesh object, just search for **Convert to Mesh** operator.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! I will go with this approach! I want to create something close to low poly dreadlocks. Works just great!

Comment: Great you found it useful :)